# How can I avoid seeing fragments of my pre-reboot screen after a reboot?

Tags: graphics, 20.04, reboot

Every time I reboot my computer, after entering my password and pressing enter, I briefly see jumbled fragments of my screen as it was right before I rebooted. I'm a bit concerned about this from a privacy/security standpoint, as it means that any information that was on the screen when I rebooted is potentially available for someone to see after rebooting. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening, for example by having Ubuntu forcibly clear/overwrite the GPU memory during shutdown?

Note: I don't use Wayland because of several disruptive issues it has, so I use X11 for both the login screen and my session.

I originally installed this system as Kubuntu 19.10, but I have since upgraded to 20.04 and switched everything to "regular" Ubuntu as much as possible, including boot animation, GDM3 as login screen, and GNOME 3 as my login session. In case it matters, the CPU is a AMD Ryzen 7 3700X, and the GPU is an AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT.

Comment: Then an attacker could simply crash your system, preventing the overwrite-at-shutdown.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.)?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: @user535733 Overwriting the GPU memory at shutdown was one example of what a solution might be. I recognize that any solution will probably not be perfect, but I'd at least like to get to the point where it doesn't happen on every reboot.

Comment: Consider filing a security bug with the driver authors. Brainstorming how to solve the problem at the OS level seems seems premature - first you must find the right folks to report it to. Perhaps they are already working on a solution.